# MIPS Assembly - how to calculate the square of n recursively

Tags: recursion, assembly, mips

I want to write a program that calculates the square of *n* using recursion based on the equation `n^2 = (n - 1)^2 + 2(n - 1) + 1`  But I don't know how to write the *nonbasecase:* part. Can anyone help?

A python program would be

```py
def square(n) {
    if (n==0):
        return 0
    else:
        return square(n-1) + 2*(n-1) + 1 
}
```

Here is what I got so far.

```
start:      
        li  $a0, 0x0003     #$a0 contains the number to be squared              
        jal square          # recursive call
        
square:     
        subi $sp, $sp, 8    # decrement the stack pointer $sp
        sw  $ra, 4($sp)     # push the return address register $ra
        sw  $a0, 0($sp)     # push argument register $a0
        li  $t0, 0x0001     # load $t0 with 1 as part of test for base case
        bne $a0, $t0, nonbasecase   # branch if not the base case
        li $v0, 0x0001      # return base result in $v0
        addi $sp, $sp 8     # recover stack space 
        jr $ra          # jump to return address in $ra

nonbasecase:    
       #not sure how to write when it is not the base case


        jr $ra          # jump to contents of return address register $ra
```

Comment: That MIPS code is doing `if (n==1) return;` which is not the same as the pseudo code, which is doing `if (n==0) return 0;`  Can you see how the `return 0` is missing?  And also it tests against 1 instead of against 0.

Comment: We are not a code writing service so you need to explain where you're having difficulty translating `return square(n-1) + 2*(n-1) + 1`.  Just decompose the expression: first make the call to `square` passing `n-1` as the argument, then compute the rest of the expression...  Don't let the recursion concept fool you, it is nothing more than a function call.

Comment: Also, finish the main code or else it will run `square` again, but this time by accident.

Answer (score 0):

Write the function so that it inputs `n2` and `n` and returns `n2+2*n+1` and `n+1`.